# Inline display leaves white space

Tags: html, alignment, css

At the bottom of [this page](http://bit.ly/V31rvN) I have a media gallery. The first three photos are the photo gallery, Inlined after it I placed some video thumbnails. For some reason the alignment of each element of the video gallery is messed up. Can you help me?

This is the HTML of each video thumbnail:

```
<?php  if((get_post_meta($post->ID, 'url_video3', true))) { ?>
<div class="video_container">
<a href="#TB_inline?inlineId=url_video3&width=600&height=400" class="thickbox video">
<?php $attachment_id = get_field('icona_video3'); echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, icona); ?>
<div class="play-icona"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/video_link.png" /></div>
</a>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

And this is the CSS:

```
.thickbox.video {
text-decoration: none !important;
width: 96px !important;
height: 96px !important;
}
.video_container {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
height: 96px !important;
width: 96px !important;
margin: 0 !important;
padding: 0 !important;
}
.play-icona {
position:absolute;
left:35%;
top:35%;
}
```

Comment: I don't see any gallery on that page, it's just a background image...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, `inline-block` elements respect surrounding whitespace (following the standard whitespace collapsing rules). If rendering an element with `inline-block` causes noticeable gaps around the element, make sure the two elements in HTML are right up against one another — if there are any newlines or spaces, they'll get translated into a gap by the web browser.

Comment: Thanks, that partially solved the problem! What's left is a whitespace between each row. BtW, I have opened the website to non-admins so you can now watch the page I am talking about.

Comment: [Here is a screenshot with the problem](https://lh.rs/CgVyU4Jh1GTV). The href just doesn't get the size of the thumbnail and creates a gap with the following row.

Comment: It's tricky to try things without having access to the page itself (the link above still doesn't seem to work). In situations like these, I usually just use the Safari (or Chrome) developer tools and modify bits of the CSS until it looks how I want.

Comment: I just opened the website, so the link in the first post is now working.